# How to make my script pause after reaching a certain condition for 1000ms

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops

I've got a setInterval script that repeats logging "Hello world" 10 times.
I would like to make it stop for 1 second after repeating 10 times, then starting again and doing the process for ever.

here is what I have:

```
var i = 0;
var x = setInterval(function(){
console.log("Hello world");
i++;
if(i >= 10){
i = 0;
stopInterval()
}
},1000);

var stopInterval = function(){
clearInterval(x);
setTimeout(function(){
//restart the interval, but how do I do???
},1000);
};
```

However, it says stopInterval is not defined and I thought it was

Comment: There is no stopInterval...there is clearInterval. And `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I know. I just thought that if i didnt put an example in i would get shouted at. I knew there was no such thing as stopinterval. But im unsure what to do

Comment: I've just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to use clearInterval and use the id that is returned from setInterval to clear it.

```
function myTimer() {
    var i = 0,
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Hello world");
        i++;
        if(i >=10){
            clearInterval(interval);
            window.setTimeout(myTimer, 1000);
        }
    },100);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Comment: I wanted it to restart again though, after the 1000 milliseconds

Comment: So make a function and call the function with setTimeout.

Comment: what do you mean? Show an example please

Answer (score 0):

just with setTimeout and Recursion [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m4w0exg4/)

```js
var i = 1;
var delay = 500;

function callMe() {
  console.log("Hello World"+i);
  document.getElementById("pri").innerHTML = "Hello World " + i;

  if (i == 11) {
    i = 1;
    delay = 1000;
    console.log("......Restart");
    document.getElementById("pri").innerHTML = "......Restart";
  } else {
    delay = 300;
  }
  
  setTimeout(callMe, delay);
  ++i;
}

window.onload = callMe;
```

```html
<div id="pri"></div>
```

Comment: `window.onload = callMe();` <-- that is wrong. It should be `window.onload = callMe;`